# Accessing input value (prefilled) in angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have my `index.html` file in which I am autofilling an `input text field`. I want to access this prefilled value from a controller in angular app.
How to do it?

---

index.html

```
//Has included the app and controller here
<input type="text" id="phoneNUmber" name="phoneNumber" ng-model="datumPhoneNumber">
```

---

app.js

```
alert($scope.datumPhoneNumber)
```

Comment: `datumPhoneNumber` != `datamPhoneNumber`

Comment: It should be accessible that way, can you show us a plunkr demonstrating the problem?